# CSS Flickering issue

Tags: html, css

lately I was making a speedometer for my FiveM server, the speedometer is connected with jQuery, everything works fine but I'm having a strange issue with the bar on it. Then the vehicle passes half of the speedometer it start to flicker , I know that it's because the half circles I made , 50% visible 50% not , is there any way to fix this ?

```css
.box-float{
    position: relative;
    right: 5vh;
    top: 34vh;
}

.box {
  --v: calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  transform: rotate(160deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%, #4c4c4e 0) 0/min(100%, (var(--p) - 50)*100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #4c4c4e 0);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 0) 0/min(100%, (50 - var(--p))*100%), linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}

  .box2 {
    --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);
    width:170px;
    left: 0.4vh;
    top: 5;
    height:170px;
    transform: rotate(160deg);
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:12px;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%, #8a8989 0) 0/min(100%, (var(--p) - 50)*100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #8a8989 0);
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 0) 0/min(100%, (50 - var(--p))*100%), linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
    mask-composite:exclude;
  }

  .box3 {
    --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);
    left: 0.4vh;
    top: 5;
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    transform: rotate(160deg);
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:12px;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%, #b7ff00 0) 0/min(100%, (var(--p) - 50)*100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #b7ff00 0);
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(var(--v), #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 0) 0/min(100%, (50 - var(--p))*100%), linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
    mask-composite:exclude;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-float relative">
      <div class="box-tekstic absolute font-bold"><a class="text-gray-400">0</a>85</div>
      <a class="box-tekstic2 absolute font-semibold text-gray-400">KM/H</a>
      <div class="box absolute" style="--p:68;"></div>
      <div class="box2 absolute" style="--p:68;"></div>
      <div class="box3 absolute"></div>
</div>
```

> Video

[Issue](https://streamable.com/j7njzj)